Proper push a file to a Git repo used by several developers
We have a relatively large code base in our repos, some containing over 20K source files.
As of now, splitting the code into smaller chunks is out of the question.
Each developer only needs a few files, thus the procedure is to perform dummy clone and then to checkout a file or some files:
git clone -n <repo>
git checkout origin/main -- path/to/file1.c path/to/file2.cob

That all works well up to the following scenario:

Developer 1 checks out file1 and modifies it.
Developer 2 checks out file2 and modifies it.
Developer 1 pushes the file1 to the repo.
Developer 2 tries to push the file2 to the repo and gets the error:

> git push
To https://github.com/<repo1>.git
 ! [rejected]        main -> main (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/<repo1>.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Now, all the solutions talk about git pull, but this would bring the whole repo to the developer's account and that is completely redundant.
What would be the right way to deal with it?
We tried to fetch and various strategies of git push, to no avail. If the second developer performs forceful push, the changes done by the first developer disappear, and this is well documented and explained in the Git documentation and other questions here.

Don't have everyone push directly into the main branch. In fact don't have anyone push into main. This is why branches and pull requests exist.


git pull, but this would bring the whole repo to the developer's account

Yes, that's fine because you already did this with git clone. Just because a branch is not checked out doesn't mean all the files haven't already been cloned locally.
Check out the master branch and use git pull --rebase as normal to resolve the conflict and push.
